# Find similarity between two documents Lucene

Tags: lucene, similarity, documents

I have indexed i.e 400 documents. Then i want to give two documents and lucene to return me the similarity between those two documents. Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In brief. calculate the cosine of two document vector.

[example code](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/10/computing-document-similarity-using.html)

Comment: Yes, but if someone wants a good similarity measure, I think that he needs a good stemmer and to remove stopwords too. Is there an easy way to do this? Except Lucene?